# variable undefined in sass

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

Everything was working fine and then all of the sudden a bunch of error appeared on the terminal, saying that I needed to install `node-sass` module. So that's what I did to fix all those errors, but now I get this error:

```
SassError: Undefined variable: "$text-weight".
```

I don't get why react is even detecting my sass files, I'm only importing the compiled vanilla css and sass is also compiled successfully with no errors.
`_variables.scss` is imported at the top using `@import` syntax.

index.scss file:

```
@import './variables';

body {
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  font-family: acumin-pro, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.App {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 10fr 0.1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

@import './navbar';
@import './carousel';
@import './user';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined your $text-weight variable in another file you should import it to the file that you are using it

Comment: that is exactly what I did, and I got a bunch of variables so if I did not imported the file _variables.scss then my live sass compiler won't even compile

Comment: As I see you have _variables.scss but you are importing ./variables which is not the same name.

Comment: you don't need to add the "_" and ".scss" when importing, vsCode removes it automatically. Haven't you tried it?

Comment: Could send the exact file that you are using $text-weight variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use @import syntax to import the file where you define your variable $text-weight.

If you are importing .scss file or .sass file somewhere in your React app, it will require you to setup node-sass to compile sass syntax into vanilla css.

Normally, people will do that in index.js or App.js where the main react component resides.

Not only React, most of the framework such as Angular will also need to setup in the boilerplate for scss or sass support.

Comment: @KevinBryan, did you happen to solve it? If still cannot, can show where you are using $text-weight variable?